# Как работает атрибут query_pk_and_slug

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

В классе `SingleObjectMixin` есть атрибут `query_pk_and_slug` не очень понятно, что он делает?

Когда он равен `True` подходит для такого URL `/home/<pk:pk>/<slug:slug>`, а `False` `/home/<pk:pk>` или `/home/<slug:slug>`?

Comment: Я в документации покопался, по сути установка этого атрибута в `True` - это просто указание методу `get_object()`, чтобы он поиск производил и по ключу и по слагу, например, чтобы при атаке на сайт нельзя было забрутфорсить `url` и так получить все объекты, а требовалось два последовательных аргумента, поэтому - да, `/home/<pk:pk>/<slug:slug>` - будет подходить, а когда он `False`, то это не меняет исходного поведения и можно по-прежнему использовать как `pk`, так и `slug`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда он равен True подходит для такого URL /home/<pk:pk>/slug:slug, а False /home/<pk:pk> или /home/slug:slug? 
Ответ: Да

1. Если query_pk_and_slug = True, функция get_object будет искать по slug и pk
2. Если query_pk_and_slug = False, функция get_object будет возвращаться по pk, если в роуте найдет <:pk>, иначе будет искать по <:slug>